# How to compile OpenCV and OpenGL together?

Tags: opengl, opencv, compilation, cmake

I want to write a program that utilizes both OpenCV and OpenGL. I tried to compile the OpenCV code that I wrote with functions from OpenGL. My code wont compile. Do you guys know if I have to add any extra lines in my CMakeLists file or if there is any other way to turn on OpenGl compatibility in my OpenCV setup?

Comment: Can you show what you have done?

Comment: this is what I have written so far for CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( redobject )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( redobject redobject.cpp )
target_link_libraries( redobject ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

Whenever I run the make command, it does not recognize any of the OpenGL functions. I have gathered enough info to know that you can turn on OpenGL compatibility in opencv. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV and OpenGL are two different library. There are no overlap between them.So to use, just include them. Follow this link to [Install OpenGL/Glut libraries in Ubuntu](http://www.kiwwito.com/article/installing-opengl-glut-libraries-in-ubuntu)